# Changing terminal buffer scrolling shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, readline, terminal-emulator

As far as I know, the keyboard shortcut for scrolling terminal buffer is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd>, and it seems to be an universal standard, which makes me suspect it's not part of the terminal emulator, but rather controlled by readline.

However, I haven't been able to find information on how to change that shortcut (in a terminal-emulator-independent way). Can you point me to correct place? Or is it impossible to change in on readline level after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These keys are handled by the terminal emulator. Readline plays absolutely no role in this story.

In `konsole` you can change the shortcuts in the profile preferences. In `gnome-terminal` these are hardwired and cannot be changed. I'm not sure about other terminal emulators, you'd need to consult the documentation or look around in the menus.

There's no way to change it in a terminal-emulator-independent way.